# r during installing lightgbm error occurs accordingly internalsID

Tags: r

During installing lightgbm in R this error occurs. I have researched about the function internalsID but couldnt find a solution.

```
install_github("Microsoft/LightGBM", subdir = "R-package")

Error:
* installing *source* package ‘lightgbm’ ...
** libs 
installing via 'install.libs.R' t
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/lightgbm
Fehler in .Internal(internalsID()) : 
es gibt keine .Internal Funktion 'internalsID'
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a nice installation-instruction on github.
[Installation of lightgbm](https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/tree/master/R-package)

This should solve your problem.

Best reguards